# Fill up a dropdown list with angular and JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an data.json file and I want to read it adn fill up a dropdown list. 
My code is:

```
 <head>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        MyPanel=angular.module('MyPanel',[]);
        MyPanel.controller('MyController', function($scope,$http){
            $http.get('feed/data.json').success(function(response){
                $scope.myData = response;
            });
        });
      </script>
    </head>
<body ng-app="MyPanel" ng-controller="myController">
    <select ui-jq="chosen" id="storeId" class="form-control m-b" >
       <option value="">Choose</option>
       <option ng:repeat="data in myData">{{myData.id}} - {{myData.name}}</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

I didin't get anything with this code. No error no dropdown list.
Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: `<option ng-repeat="data in myData"> {{data.id}} - {{data.name}}</option>` Try that instead

Comment: I tried but doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: after you set `$scope.myData = response` can you log it? like `console.log($scope.myData);` just to see what you get as response

Comment: That's very strange. In chrome load the list fine, but in firefox doesn't load the list. I can't understand why this happen

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here: `ng:repeat`, it should be `ng-repeat`

btw i highly suggest you to use `ng-options` instead https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 0):

By changing your code to:

```
<option ng-repeat="data in myData"> {{data.id}} - {{data.name}}</option>
```

Your select should work, but it seems you have other issues, the first thing you can do is to log the response in your `$http.get`

```
   $http.get('feed/data.json').success(function(response){
            console.log(response)
            $scope.myData = response;
        });
```

Just to see that we actually are getting some data.

You could also try and create some test data

```
$scope.myData = [
    {id: 1, name: 'test1'},
    {id: 2, name: 'test2'} ];
```

also comment out `// $scope.myData = response;`

If your `ng-repeat` works with the test data, your problem is not with ng-repeat, but in the `$http.get` request